# Input with PHP action

Tags: php, html

I am trying to learn some PHP. I have a school assignment that if i have a input that the input has to do a action in PHP and that it has to print something out. (I hope you guys understand what i mean :) )

```
<?php
$test = $_POST[ 'test'];
$prijs = 10;

if ($test > 65){
    echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test <= 12){
    echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test < 3){
    echo $prijs / 10;
} else if ($test > 12){
    echo $prijs;
}

?>

<html>
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="test" id="input" type="text"  >
</form>
</html>
```

But this doesnt seems to work for me? What am i missing or doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

EDIT:
The input needs to be printed out. So if i have a input 13, it needs to show 10. Or if i have a input 2, it needs to show 1.

Comment: What you want to input? not clear

Comment: how to submitting your `form`

Comment: if you have school assignment that learn it do by yourself by googling

Comment: If i use a number like 5, it doesnt show the print out. So input 5 needs to show prijs = 5 or input 13 has to show prijs = 10

Comment: First of all, there's no body in your HTML. you should have a `<body> ... </body>` tag where the form and input goes. Also, the php code should be there too, since you're going to print the result in the body too, aren't you?

Comment: Hi Jabirr,

I suggest to take a tour at https://www.codecademy.com/ (for `HTML` and `PHP`). 
Other documentations can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp.

In your example you are not working with proper `HTML` tags to display `PHP` at all.

Comment: Okay thx, i will look at it:)

Comment: ^^ You dont need HTML to print strings in PHP.

Comment: Your php conditions are not correct. if you will put 2 then it will give print 5 as `2 <= 12` your second condition

Comment: If you have an input=2 as you say you will get 5 because it will match the criteria of your first else_if

Comment: How can i fix my php conditions then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$test = $_POST[ 'test'];
$prijs = 10;

if ($test > 65){
    echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test <= 12 && $test >=3){
    echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test < 3){
    echo $prijs / 10;
} else if ($test > 12){
    echo $prijs;
}
```

This will solve the bug of the second statement.
If you want to print your input you just `echo $test` inside your `if statements.`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

add `isset()` for check your `$_POST['test']` set value or not

and  add `<input type="submit" value="submit">` for submitting the form after you submit form its value get in `php`

```
<?php
$test = isset($_POST[ 'test'])?$_POST[ 'test']:'';
$prijs = 10;
if ($test > 65){
    echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test <= 12){
    echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test < 3){
    echo $prijs / 10;
} else if ($test > 12){
    echo $prijs;
}

?>

<html>
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="test" id="input" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx i am adding it

Answer (score 0):

Thx Bhargav and pr1nc3,
I have mixed the codes you 2 send me and added a few things. And now its working correctly :)

```
<?php
$test = isset($_POST[ 'test'])?$_POST[ 'test']:'';
$prijs = 10;

$a = "Je betaalt ";
$b = " Euro ";

if ($test > 65){
    echo $a . $prijs / 2 . $b;
} else if ($test <= 12 && $test >=3){
    echo $a . $prijs / 4 . $b;
} else if ($test >= 1  && $test <= 3){
    echo $a . $prijs / 10 . $b;
} else if ($test > 12){
    echo $a. $prijs . $b;
}

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">

    <input name="test" id="input" type="text" placeholder="Hoe oud ben je?">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make submit button to submit the formand make action to same file like,

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST[ 'test'])){ 
 $test = $_POST[ 'test'];
 $prijs = 10;

if ($test > 65){
  echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test <= 12){
   echo $prijs / 2 ;
} else if ($test < 3){
   echo $prijs / 10;
} else if ($test > 12){
   echo $prijs;
}
}
?>

<html>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <input name="test" id="input" type="text"  >
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

this `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>` will make action to the same file and your php code executes.

Hope it helps you,
Thanks.